# Javascript in WebView rendering issues

Tags: javascript, java, swing, webview, chart.js

I'm not new to coding but I am new to using WebView to display HTML.
My Java swing project requires charts and graphs, and I think the prettiest out there is Chart.js.
To display the javascript-created charts, I save progmatically created html and read it in to a browser (WebView page) in a JPanel (through Javafx).

Here is my issue:
Chart.js (and my created HTML files) run fine in a real web browser, but in WebView they have really odd glitches that destroy my graphs (covering datapoints, etc). As far as I've seen, these glitches only occur in radial graphs such as Pie, Donut, and Radar.
I've even visited the chart.js webpage (through my app) and the examples on their homepage also have the same glitches. I have the updated, stable version of their open source code...

**What i've tried:**

- messing with background/css in html
- messing with parameters in chart creation, such as stroke controls or animations
- drawing different graphs with different number of datapoints with different values

**What I haven't tried:**

- I'm not too familiar with Javascript so i haven't gone in to debug its main chart.js javascript file yet.

An example of what a sample graph looks like in any **real web browser**:
[good pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crllS.png)

And an example of what the same graph looks like in **my java app**: [bad pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tFIe.png)

Please help!

Comment: Same problem here with radial pie and doughnut charts running Chart.js 2.0 in JavaFX in Oracle JRE 1.80_60-b27 ... bar charts and line graphs run fine with animation and UI updates.